# Reference issue with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerification,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../../config/firebase";
import _ from "lodash";

import { db } from "../../config/firebase";
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  getDoc,
  query,
  getDocs,
  QuerySnapshot,
  where,
  orderBy,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export const firebase_GetProgramDetails = createAsyncThunk(
  "programDetailsSlice/firebase_GetProgramDetails",
  async (programID, ThunkAPI) => {
    const state = ThunkAPI.getState().programDetails;
    ThunkAPI.dispatch(pushProgramDetails());

    try {
      const querySnapshotDays = await getDocs(
        query(
          collection(db, "programs", programID, "Days"),
          orderBy("dayNumber", "asc")
        )
      );

      querySnapshotDays.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const exercises = [];
        const querySnapshotExercises = await getDocs(
          query(
            collection(db, "programs", programID, "Days", doc.id, "exercises"),
            orderBy("order", "asc")
          )
        );

        querySnapshotExercises.forEach(async (exe) => {
          exercises = [];
          const exercise = exe.data()["exercise"];
          const exeData = await getDoc(exercise);
          const exeName = await exeData.data()["exerciseName"];
          exercises.push({
            ...exe.data(),
            exerciseName: exeName,
          });
        });
        console.log(querySnapshotExercises.docs);
        ThunkAPI.dispatch(
          pushProgramDetails({ ...doc.data(), exercises: exercises })
        );
      });

      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      return ThunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

export const programDetailsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "programDetails",
  initialState: {
    status: "idle",
    programDetails: [],
    msg: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    reset: (state, action) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.status = "idle";
      state.programDetails = [];
      state.msg = "";
    },
    pushProgramDetails: (state, action) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.programDetails = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(firebase_GetProgramDetails.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
        state.msg = "";
      })
      .addCase(firebase_GetProgramDetails.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
      })
      .addCase(firebase_GetProgramDetails.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.msg = action.payload;
        state.programDetails = [];
      });
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { reset, pushProgramDetails } = programDetailsSlice.actions;

export default programDetailsSlice.reducer;
```

I have nested collections. So for a program I am getting the days and for each day I get the exercises for it. I push all of that into an array of objects. If I pass it to the state to be set I keep getting none extendable error which I think it is because it is soft copy that is being passed.

After the first run and set of the state second run it would raise an error.

I tried hard copy it keeps copying an empty array. Any idea of there is an easier way to do it?

I am just trying to get everything into a array of objects "Array is sorted to days order" then put it into the state to display it.

Comment: This post is pretty incomprehensible. Can you [edit] to clarify what specifically the issue is that you are trying to resolve? If there's an error, please include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for not explaining my question clearly. So after fetching my query from firebase, I ran foreach do get the sub collection. The problem was I get the results of these queries I push it to an array and return. But React + Redux on strict mode runs twice and foreach is not async The temporary array causing an error not extendable since it’s being accessed again. It just needed me to change it to for loop and await. Also this method is not efficient. I ended up querying the collections up front then loop through it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).